# I want Ascending 2nd div inside li..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

This Is My ul li div Structure

```
<ul id="Section">
   <li>
      <div id="ui-id-2" style="float:left;">Qole Shahroye</div>
      <div id="syriacname-1" style="float:right;">ܩ̈ܠܐ ܫܝ/div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div id="ui-id-2" style="float:left;">Qole Shahroye</div>
      <div id="syriacname-2" style="float:right;">ܩ̈ܠܐ ܫܗ</div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div id="ui-id-2" style="float:left;">Qole Shahroye</div>
      <div id="syriacname-3" style="float:right;">ܩ̈ܠܐ ܫܗܪ̈ܝܐ</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CheckBox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ascsection" value="" />
```

On this checkbox click my li Ascending But I Want Ascending My 2nd div inside li

```
$(".ascsection").click(function(){              

    var items = $('#Section li').get();
        items.sort(function(a,b){
                var keyA = $(a).text();
                var keyB = $(b).text();

                if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
                if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
                return 0;
        });

        var ul = $('#Section');
            $.each(items, function(i, li){
               ul.append(li);
            });

});
```

This Is My Whole Code Ascending, But In This Code Through On Click Checkbox li Value Ascending But I Want Ascending 2nd Div Value Inside Li

Thanks In Advance.Please Do

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the same `ID` multiple times

Comment: but i want ascending that id through..give me any idea..?

Comment: `ID`'s have to be unique, so use class instead

Comment: ok i take unique id .please do i have no idea.

Comment: Take a look below at my answer and tell me if it solves your problem

Comment: No.Check My Comment Below.Understand My Question Proper

Comment: First, your question is kinda bad written, so sorry if I miss read it. You use a capital letter for every word, aka that's bad. Anyway, have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: Yes Its Work Perfect. I Give Big Karma

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen " jsfiddle.net/Kaushik007/qtbc9mt0 "
Please check this jsfiddle.  When click on checkbox, i want ul > li > first div text Should be Ascending. The country div text should not be ascending It should stay as it is. This code is working but not as per my requirement. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I Need your help. please see my question.                                                                                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064447/i-want-ascending-1st-div-text-inside-ul-li

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen im new developer so please i need your help. Thank in advance

Comment: do you Think I'm just a "come when i Call and fix my code" person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Id's` to `class` since `ID` have to be unique.

```js
$(".ascsection").click(function(){              

    var items = $('#Section li .syriacname').get();
        items.sort(function(a,b){
                var keyA = $(a).text();
                var keyB = $(b).text();

                if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
                if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
                return 0;
        });
       
        

        var ul = $('#Section li');
            $.each(items, function(i, li){
               ul.eq(i).append(li);
            });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Section">
   <li>
      <div class="ui-id-2" style="float:left;">Qole Shahroye</div>
      <div class="syriacname" style="float:right;">c</div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="ui-id-2" style="float:left;">Qole Shahroye</div>
      <div class="syriacname" style="float:right;">b</div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="ui-id-2" style="float:left;">Qole Shahroye</div>
      <div class="syriacname" style="float:right;">a</div>
   </li>
</ul>
<input type="checkbox" class="ascsection" value="" />
```

Comment: but i dont ascending li.only ascending 2nd div value inside li.my first div value as it is and only ascending 2nd div understand..?

Comment: @K-Series Try it now, i changed the values of the div's so I could test it